# Why is EOSJS JsSignatureProvider considered insecure?

Tags: javascript, blockchain, eos

In the eosjs docs (https://developers.eos.io/manuals/eosjs/latest/faq/what-is-a-signature-provider) it's said that JsSignatureProvider is insecure. Why exactly it's insecure?
I'm kinda new and would like to use it in my backend pet project.
I feel like if I'm gonna write my own signature provider I would just reinvent eosjs JsSignatureProvider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason why `JsSignatureProvider` is insecure is that the constructor takes the private keys directly to perform the signing (which can be exposed to potential attack vectors, i.e., malicious extensions, etc.).

A more secure way may be to route the signing requests to a secure enclave without exposing the private keys, perform the signing there, and get back the signature.